# Form input not being recognized after submit in code behind

Tags: html, forms, post

Title says it all. I submit a form, call a function in the code behind but the value for the form is always null.

I've tried quite a few scenarios, I'll post my current state to see if there is a simple fix I am missing or better solution.

I don't know if this impact things but this code lies on .ascx page.

**Pertinent JS/jQuery**

```
function forceClick() {

    <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(hiddenBtn, string.Empty) %>;
    }


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id$=ImageButton2]').click(function () {
        console.log($('[id$=buttontest]'));
        console.log($('[id$=ImageButton2]'));
        $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
            title: "Delete Item",
            buttons: {
                Submit: function () {
                    forceClick();
                    $('#myForm').submit();

                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Close: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },

            modal: true
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**Pertinent HTML**

```
<div id="modal_dialog" style="display: none">
    <p class="validateTips">Please enter a reason for deleting the item.</p>
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="Detail.ascx">
        <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment"/>    
    </form> 
</div>
```

**Code-behind**

```
    protected void buttontest_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string commentOne = Request.Form["comment"];



        Session["ItemCount"] = null;
        if (DeleteItem != null)
        {
            DeleteItem(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note: there is a form on the .aspx page and is why there is no runat="server".

Comment: action="Detail.ascx" - form action points to a user control?

Comment: whose method is `buttontest_OnClick` and why do you expect it to be called when you call `$('#myForm').submit();`?

Comment: @Igor I am trying to execute the code behind on the user control that sits on the .aspx page. I may doing this incorrectly but the previous delete logic is set that way.

the forceClick() method calls the buttontest_Onclick